# Aplicativo cordova não abre no dispositivo ao comandar 'RUN' e não loga erros

Tags: android, apache-cordova, app

Tenho uma aplicação HTML e não consigo faze-la rodar em android no modo teste. Estou usando Mac OS, mas quando usava Linux tudo funcionava perfeitamente com o comando "cordova run android": o app era instalado no dispositivo e aberta automaticamente. Agora tudo esta ocorrendo ok, mas o app não instala no dispositivo muito menos roda. Ele ate chega a acender o visor mas nada a partir dai.

Algumas informações úteis.

1. Java JDK instalado corretamente.
2. Todas API's do android desde a 17.
3. Plataforma mais recente estável do android no diretório de aplicação.
4. Dispositivo conectado e modo de depuração ativo.

Nada errado aparentemente, vejam:

```
Rodolfos-MacBook-Pro:cordbuild2 rodolpho_paranhos$ sudo cordova run android
Running command: "/Users/rodolpho_paranhos/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projetos/Pray/cordbuild2/platforms/android/cordova/run" 
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device 'LGOTMS5a4ccfc'.
Running: /Users/rodolpho_paranhos/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projetos/Pray/cordbuild2/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/rodolpho_paranhos/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projetos/Pray/cordbuild2/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.264 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /Users/rodolpho_paranhos/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projetos/Pray/cordbuild2/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: /Users/rodolpho_paranhos/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projetos/Pray/cordbuild2/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
Rodolfos-MacBook-Pro:cordbuild2 rodolpho_paranhos$
```

Comment: Mas ele chega a instalar o App no dispositivo? Já tentou remover o App manualmente e tentar executar o comando novamente. Outra coisa que pode tentar é gerar o APK e instalar manualmente ele. Sempre tenho problemas com projetos quando troco de ambiente de desenvolvimento. Quase sempre recrio o projeto e adiciono o código fonte que criei.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Já fiz de tudo. Só instala pelo adb, dai fica complicado ter que buildar depois instalar. Comprei outro smartphone e funcionou tranquilo. O problema era no dispositivo mesmo